# Build fail in java

Tags: java, ant

I am try to build my java application in command prompt, but it fails as..

```
compile-core:
    [javac] Compiling 1085 source files to c:\conet\app\build\core
    [javac]
    [javac]
    [javac] The system is out of resources.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

BUILD FAILED
C:\conet\app\build.xml:324: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 minute 5 seconds
C:\conet\app>
```

Any solution for this type of problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using ant, you should increase the available heap size for compilation. Add this to your build.xml compilation target:

```
memoryinitialsize="256m"
memorymaximumsize="1024m"
```

Info taken from [here](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/06/fix-javac-java-lang-outofmemoryerror.html).

Comment: in which file I have to add this

Comment: @Amit: build.xml; if you're not sure where to put it, edit your question and add its contents so we can see what it looks like

Comment: I set fork attribute to true through your link in build.xml and solved .. Thanks darioo

Answer (score 0):

If Java runs out of memory, the following error occurs:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
This can have two reasons:

1. Your Java application has a memory leak. There are tools like YourKit Java Profiler that help you to identify such leaks.
2. Your Java application really needs a lot of memory (more than 128 MB by default!). In this case the Java heap size can be increased using the following runtime parameters:

   javac -Xms`<initial heap size>` -Xmx`<maximum heap size>`

Defaults are:

```
javac -Xms32m -Xmx128m
```

Please increase the memory accordingly as required.

Comment: I have done javac -Xms512m -Xmx512m... but still same problem

Comment: What is the size of your RAM ?

Comment: You could get the free space of your VM, too (which is your bottle neck); Also you can go through this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s